# Почему Dropdown не скрывается при нажатии на ссылку?

Tags: bootstrap, reactjs, react-router

В варианте на верхней картинке дропдаун при нажатии на ссылку (LinkContainer) скрывается, но если выделить 3 обведённые строчки в отдельный компонент (MenuItemLink), то уже не скрывается (не рендерится ServiceMenu)
Использую react, react-bootstrap, react-router-bootstrap

[image: код]

Comment: **Не рендерится `ServiceMenu`** - это как? Что-то я не совсем понял. Приведите пример того, как вы выделяете в отдельный компонент, нет ли ошибок в консоли браузера. Больше деталей.

Comment: ошибок в консоли нет. отдельный компонент указан на 2х нижних изображениях. то есть вместо 3х строчек, выделенных розовым <LinkKontainer>... я пишу 1 строчку <MenuItemLink>. Не рендерится - значит что при нажатии на ссылку во втором случае не вызывается рендер компонента ServiceMenu